# How to get list of available functions and their parameters in KDB/Q?

Tags: kdb

How would I go about getting a list of available functions and their parameters in a given namespace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#f-functions

```
\f .
\f .namspace
```

For functions you will have to check parameters individually by just giving the name of function

```
.n.function
```

will give you not only the parameters but the whole function definition.

Comment: I figured out that `get` could get me the parameters for a given function. http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/get

Answer (score 4):

this can surely be improved upon, but thought I'd share as a quick way to get the ball rolling. This will retrieve every global user defined function in every workspace and create a dictionary of namespapaces to functions to parameters.

```
 q)getparams:{k!{n[w]!@'[;1] value each f w:where 100h=type each f:get each ".",/:"." sv/:string x,/:n:y x}[;m]  each key m:k!system each "f .",/:string k:key `}
 q)f1:{x+y+z}
 q).n1.f2:{x*x}
 q).n1.a:2
 q).n2.f3:{y+y}
 q)show r:getparams[]
 q | `aj`aj0`asc`asof`avgs`cols`cor`cov`cross`cut`desc`dev`each`ej`except`fby`..
 Q | `Cf`IN`L`S`V`addmonths`bv`chk`cn`d0`dd`def`dpft`dpt`dsftg`dt`en`f`fc`ff`f..
 h | `cd`code`data`eb`ec`ed`edsn`es`fram`ha`hb`hc`hn`hr`ht`hta`htac`htc`html`h..
 n1| (,`f2)!,,`x
 n2| (,`f3)!,`x`y
q)r[`n1;`f2]
,`x
```

[EDIT] the original function was wrong. It missed the global namespace (`) and didn't capture composition, or functions defined with an adverb. The below corrects this, but seems overly convoluted. I'll still leave it here though in case anyone wants to post a nicer solution (so that I too can learn from that)

```
  getparams:{k!{n[w][w2]!@'[;1] v w2:where 0h=type each v:value/[{type[x] in y}[;t]; ] each f:f w:where in[ ;(t:"h"$100,105+til 7)] type each f:get each `$".",/:"." sv/:string x,/:n:y x}[;m]  each key m:k!system each "f .",/:string k:`,key `}
```

Comment: I realize this an old thread but is there a way to reference just the first, blank name space i.e. I just want to build a dictionary of my custom functions vs. the native q functions?  Thanks in advance, a very helpful thread!

Answer (score 2):

I addition to Naveen's answer, you can call `value functionName` which will give you a list of items, e.g. parameter names and the compiled byte code